# How to fix bug "Authentication is needed to run '/usr/share/-apport/dump_acpi_tables.py' as the super user"?

Tags: 20.04, bug-reporting, debugging, su

I get an internal error (involving xorg), logging me out and then I have to log back in (restarting any apps, since they were all closed), then I get this error, which I've seen is a bug, but I'm not sure how to deal with it. Any ideas?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: @24601 I think it's already been reported as a bug, I'm just not sure if there is anything that can be done about it. I don't think being logged out and having to restart everything when I click on "settings" is normal

Comment: try with 'sudo bash', then run (will be run as root), then 'sudo -u <username> bash'  to get out of root. Obviously, you will be in root mode, so extreme caution is necessary...  Not sure why the shell sees sudo and root differently, but it does. Not sure if you are looking for a temp workaround, but this is what I use in this type of situation. may be a good idea to automate, so the command line is never actually in root mode

Comment: The more people who report/confirm it as a bug, the more likely it will be addressed.